# C# Internet radio if not play

Tags: c#, windows-media-player, internet-radio

Need check if radio play, and reload if not

```
class Program
{
    Random random = new Random();
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        WindowsMediaPlayer WMPs = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer(); //создаётся плеер 
        WMPs.settings.volume = 100;
        WMPs.URL = "http://stream.brandradionetworks.com:8000/citrus";
        WMPs.controls.play(); // start playing
        Time();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find out if it is playing (or waiting, buffering etc) by using the [playState property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmp/player-playstate).

"Playing" is the value 3, so for example:

```
if (WMPs.playState != 3)
{
    // handle it not playing
}
```

See also the [PlayStateChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmp/player-player-playstatechange) which will allow you to handle this a bit more elegantly.